# See last notifications from notify send in I3

Tags: i3, notifications

Is it possible to see the last notifications, that were send through notify send? Sometimes, i just miss the notification and want to see it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what notification deamon you are using.

If you are using [dunst](https://dunst-project.org/), which is often used with i3, you can access the history with `` ctrl + ` ``

You can change the key in `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc`:

```
# Redisplay last message(s).
# On the US keyboard layout "grave" is normally above TAB and left
# of "1". Make sure this key actually exists on your keyboard layout,
# e.g. check output of 'xmodmap -pke'
history = ctrl+grave
```

If you are on Ubuntu using notify-osd, [this may help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history).